# Getting python extensions to work in Albert

Tags: python, albert

I installed Albert on Ubuntu 18.04 from here:
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert

Then I cloned the Github python extensions repo as described here:
https://github.com/albertlauncher/python .

How can I enable the plugins? (Like *units* or *window-switcher*)

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/albertlauncher/python.git "~/.local/share/albert/org.albert.extension.python/modules"`

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to unless you want send your own developed extensions upstream. This repository is shipped with albert. Just enable the Python extension. Don't forget to enable the Python modules you want as well. For terminology and more info see the [Python extension docs](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/extensions/python/).

Answer (score 1):

Ah this was unfortunate. I activated "Python" in the "Extensions" Tab in Settings already.

*units* and *window-switcher* didnt work, not because of the python-extensions not working in general, but they were missing dependencies (for units it was numbpy and for window-switcher it was wmctrl).

Comment: Units needs gnu units not numpy